# How can I give arguments from list elements to a class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to giving arguments from several lists to a class.
I tried these:

```
for i in range(len(myList)): # or just myList
    myList.append(MyClass(names[i], cities[i], ages[i], problems[i]))
```

or

```
for i in range(len(myList)):

    name = names[i]
    city = cities[i]
    age = ages[i]
    problem = problems[i]

    myList.append(MyClass(name, city, age, problem))
```

But it didn't work and there is no error when i print myList it's just empty. I am probably making a wrong logic but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the length from one of your lists populated with data instead. If myList is empty before the for loop starts it will iterate zero times because len(myList) == 0.

Use e.g. `for i in range(names):` instead. Assuming your lists with data (`names`, `cities`, `ages` and `problems`) has the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists.

```
result = []
for data in zip(names, cities, ages, problems):
    name = data[0]
    city = data[1]
    age = data[2]
    problem = data[3]
    result.append(MyClass(name, city, age, problem))
```

Let's use tuple unpacking with this approach.

```
result = []
for name, city, age, problem in zip(names, cities, ages, problems):
    result.append(MyClass(name, city, age, problem))
```

All of this can be written in one line using a list comprehension.

```
result = [MyClass(name, city, age, problem) for name, city, age, problem in zip(names, cities, ages, problems)]
```

Or let Python do the tuple unpacking for you

```
result = [MyClass(*data) for data in zip(names, cities, ages, problems)]
```